# Rendering differences between phantomjs and my web browser

Tags: javascript, html, rendering, screenshot, phantomjs

I am trying to take a screenshot from a webpage with PhantomJS.  I use the following code (which works) :

```
    var args = phantom.args;
    var Address = args[0];
    var Destination = args[1];
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.viewportSize = { width: 1349, height: 653 };
    page.open(Address, function () {
        page.render(Destination);
        phantom.exit();
    });
```

Unfortunately, the image I get from PhantomJS has some differences with what I see in my browser (chrome and firefox).  The text is sometime larger, the button does not have the same behavior, ...

Does anyone could explain why or how to get the exact screenshot of what I see in my browser ?  Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [rasterize.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js) example and the wiki [page](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture) here.

Sometimes you need to delay rendering a few seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, even with the use of setTimeout as in raterize.js, the result differs from what I see in my web browser.